# Rotating view controllers within a hierarchy of View Controller -> Tab Bar Controller -> Navigation Controller -> View Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller

My app has a view controller hierarchy set up like this:

```
UIViewController
    |
UITabBarController
    |
    UINavigationController
    |  |
    |  UIViewController (*)
    |
    UINavigationController
       |
       UIViewController (*)
```

Why my UIViewController (*) don't get (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration method?

When my app has a view controller hierarchy set up like this:

```
UITabBarController
    |
    UINavigationController
    |  |
    |  UIViewController (*)
    |
    UINavigationController
       |
       UIViewController (*)
```

UIViewController (*) get (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a view controller containment issue. If you're targeting iOS 5, you can use the [new `UIViewController` methods for containment](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (see *Managing Child View Controllers*). Otherwise, you need to forward the rotation messages from your root `UIViewController` to the `UITabBarViewController`.

Comment: "you need to forward the rotation messages from your root UIViewController to the UITabBarViewController." - how to do this?

Comment: Override `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` (and other rotation callbacks if you need) in your root `UIViewController`, and call `[self.tabBarController willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:]`. That's assuming your root `UIViewController` holds a reference to the `UITabBarController` it is presenting.

Answer (score 1):

All your UIViewControllers inside UITabBarController should support autorotation in order to allow rotation for UITabBarController. Place this code in all `UIViewController (*)`:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
   return YES;
}
```